# Creating models with many variables

Tags: codeigniter

Can anyone help me interpret this code?

What does `$gallery = false` mean?  Why mention it instead of just erasing it?

models/post_model.php

```
public function post($post_parent_ID, $gallery = false)
{
}
```

Comment: those are default arguments, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for an explanation and example. They work in many languages including php.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to pass any default value for any argument, you need to write it like this.
2. **Then why it's false** - Because by default, you don't like to use it. But you have kept an option for future use. Now when you pass second argument with any other value, it will work. Otherwise, your function will work by using first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters can sometimes be optional, which means they don't need to contain any data.

```
public function post($post_parent_ID, $gallery = false)
{
}
```

Means that when I'd send something to this function I can do:

```
$this->post(1);
or
$this->post(1, 2);
```

Inside the post function you would check wether `$gallery` is filled or not depending on the use needed.